# SDE with non-degenerate diffusion visits every point

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

I am asking an extension of the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424273/for-a-sde-with-smooth-transition-densities-if-every-point-is-path-accessible) for SDEs of the Ito form.

Consider the SDE $dX_t =\sigma(X_t) dW_t$, where $W$ is a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion and  $\sigma:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ is a bounded and sufficiently regular (such as Lipschitz continuous and differentiable) function. We assume $\sigma\sigma^\top$ is non-degenerate, i.e., its minimum eigenvalue is uniformly bounded away from zero.

I am wondering under which regularity condition of $\sigma$,  one can show that for each $t>0$ and nonempty open ball $B\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have that $\mathbb{P}(X_t\in B)>0$.

---

I could not find a precise reference for the result. I have tried to prove the solution $X_t$ has a strictly positive density.
The  uniformly bounded below assumption on $\sigma$ ensures the existence of a density. However, I am not sure how to argue the density is strictly positive.
The result is argued for the one-dimensional setting with additive noises [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267477/probability-that-sde-visits-any-point).
For multiplicative noises, a result has been given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424273/for-a-sde-with-smooth-transition-densities-if-every-point-is-path-accessible) for smooth $\sigma$ and SDEs of the Stratonovich form.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the other answer is providing a reference for *existence of a density function* and you are more interested in *topological density of the support of $X_t$*.

The support of the whole trajectory $X$ in $\mathcal C([0,\infty),\mathbb R^n)$ is described by the so-called Stroock-Varadhan support theorem. In [*On the support of diffusion processes with applications to the strong maximum principle*](https://projecteuclid.org/proceedings/berkeley-symposium-on-mathematical-statistics-and-probability/Proceedings-of-the-Sixth-Berkeley-Symposium-on-Mathematical-Statistics-and/Chapter/On-the-support-of-diffusion-processes-with-applications-to-the/bsmsp/1200514345?tab=ChapterArticleLink), their Theorem 3.1 ensures that the (unique) solution to the martingale problem associated with $\frac12(\sigma\sigma^*)^{ij}\partial_i\partial_j$ has full support provided $\sigma$ is bounded continuous non-degenerate (possibly non-uniformly).

Since a solution to the SDE $\mathrm dX_t = \sigma(X_t)\mathrm dW_t$ will always be a solution to the martingale problem, it proves that $X$ has full support, which is much stronger than $X_t$ having full support. That said, if $\sigma$ is not regular enough (say locally Lipschitz) then you may have to resort to other results to prove existence of a solution (or just declare the solution to be the solution to the martingale problem; in the continuous non-denegerate case, we have existence and uniqueness).